# Can't rotate screens

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I have a dual monitor setup and want to rotate one of the two screens, I looked up how to do it, but I get an error:

```
{20:17}~ ➭ xrandr   
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 345mm x 194mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected
HDMI1 disconnected
HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x576i       50.1  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   720x480i       60.1     60.1  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected
{20:17}~ ➭ xrandr --output HDMI2 --rotate left
xrandr: output HDMI2 cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"
```

So why can't I rotate the HDMI2 output? I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I use the NVIDIA driver.

Answer (score 4):

The only way that I was able to rotate external monitor was by disabling nVida driver and enabling Intel driver in Nvidia's X Server Settings.

**Note:** Remember to log out after enabling Intel driver.

[image: Nvida X Server]

Comment: Besides being able to rotate the screen with this change did you notice any other changes to performance and display quality etc?

Comment: No I have not noticed any changes that would impact display quality.

Comment: It's unacceptable to have to use the intel driver for rotating the screen. https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999654/linux/randr-rotation-doesn-t-work/post/5108881/#5108881